# write a simple program to use stack

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to write a simple program to use stack in it
I have written a class which defines methods:

```
    public interface Stack<E>{
         public int size();

        public boolean isEmpty();

       public E top();

      public void push(E element);
      public E pop()throws EmptyStackException;
  }
```

and another class for implementing Stack:

```
    public abstract class myStack<E> implements Stack<E>{

private final E s[];
int t=0;

public myStack() {
    this.s = (E[]) new Object[100];
}


@Override
public int size(){
    return t;
}


@Override
public boolean isEmpty(){
    switch(size()){
        case 0:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public E top() {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return s[t-1];
}

@Override
public void push(E element) {
    if(isEmpty())
        s[0]= element;
    else
        s[t]= element;
    t++;
}


@Override
public E pop() {
            E x;
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    else{
        x = s[t-1];
        s[t-1] = null;
        t--;
    }
    return x;
}
}
```

for testing these code I have written another class that contains main():

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Stack<Integer> s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

but when I run the program it gives me this Error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException"

I have checked this program several times but I really can't understand what is the problem

can anyone please help me??
thanks for your attention in advance

Comment: Your program cannot possibly compile, let alone run.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This is one of the greatest riddles: Why do newbees think they can lie to us?

Comment: @Ingo Let's not be so harsh, give the benefit of a doubt :)

Comment: Voted to close, because poster did not give stacktrace, instead lied to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `abstract` keyword from the class declaration `myStack` and do the below in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Stack<Integer> s=new myStack<Integer>();
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Now it should be a compile time error saying "`Variable  is not initialized`".

**`EDIT:`**

add `throws EmptyStackException` to `top()` in `Stack` interface and in `myStack` class. And same i.e.  `throws EmptyStackException` for `pop()` function in `myStack` class not in interface, it's already there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why is it incomplete implementation, i see it is implementing all the defined methods in interface. Do i miss something here?

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll down. Still getting used to the new "cool" GUI which doesn't show scrollbars until you try to scroll...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok. No probs :).

Comment: @Trying thanks now The code prints 2 which is the expected output But the Error sign has remain in Stack class. Can you again help me to solve it ?

Comment: @ShN see my edit now. Does it answer your queries?